# Android SQLiteDatabase query ignore spaces

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I know if I want to do a SQLite `SELECT` by ignoring the spaces of `username` column in the DB, I can do:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE REPLACE(username, ' ', '') LIKE '%TO_QUERY%'
```

But the interface of `SQLiteDatabase.query()` is:

```
public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
```

I am wondering how I can implement the above SQL command using this interface, or it's better to use `SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this simply using `SQLiteOpenHelper` and `rawQuery()` method of `SQLiteDatabase`

Extend `SQLiteOpenHelper` in your class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
```

Check this.

```
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
```

To Select some columns:

```
Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE REPLACE(username, ' ', '') LIKE '%TO_QUERY%' ;", null);
```

Then do your operation using cursor `c`

To update something

```
myDataBase.execSQL("UPDATE some_table SET some_column='" + value
                + "' WHERE some_column LIKE '" + some_value + "'");
```

Comment: Thanks, seems `rawQuery()` is my best choice.